# HTTP headers became lowercased

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the html page. After submit button was pressed the request is being sent. My problem is that request's headers are downcased! I use IE because it is corporative limits.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function AjaxRequest(url,callback,method){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange= function(){
                if(req.readyState != 4) return;
                callback(req);
        }
        req.open(method,url,true);

        var hdrsArr =  document.getElementById('headers').value.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hdrsArr.length; i++){
            var p = hdrsArr[i].split('=');
            req.setRequestHeader(p[0],p[1]);
        }

        var params =  document.getElementById('params').value ;
        req.send(params);
}
function AjaxResponse(res){}
function MakeRequst(){
        alert('');
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/test-servlet/TestServlet";
        AjaxRequest(url,AjaxResponse,"POST");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' id="headers" size="200" value='key=value&SOAPAction=requestCreditBureau&Content-Type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8&Accept=text/xml'/><br>
<input type='text' id="params" size="200" value='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CB_Document appl="00000000000127725161" >[....]</CB_Document>'/><br>
<input type='button' value='doPost' onClick="MakeRequst();"/><br>
<div id="response_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

By HTTP RFC 2616, header field names are case-insensitive. Quote from it below:

> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names
>   are case-insensitive**. The field value MAY be preceded by any amount of
>   LWS, though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be extended
>   over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one SP
>   or HT. Applications ought to follow "common form", where one is known
>   or indicated, when generating HTTP constructs, since there might exist
>   some implementations that fail to accept anything

This is standard behaviour, and all browsers bar IE6 conform to this. As such, if this poses a problem to you, you will have serious issues changing the `XMLHttpRequest` object behaviour (it is not userland-modifiable). What are you doing with the headers?

(Fortune cookie of the day: **make your app strict on what it sends, lenient on what it receives** applies perfectly to this. Expect to receive a mix of lower-case, upper-case, camelcase headers... But conform to RFCs on everything you send)

Comment: Thanks! I send headers to our partners application which is case-sensitive and waits SOAPAction (not soapaction) parameter..

Comment: Kindly point them to RFC 2616 and tell them to **start following standards**? :-) More seriously, there is sadly no way to do what you want on the client side. You can either proxy requests through a local script or modify the receiver. Those are your only two "real" options, I'm afraid.

Comment: (If you're in a business relationship with those partners, you can get them to freak out on this based on technical incompetence, by the way. It's worth squeezing them a bit, you've got the upper hand and they probably know it.)

Answer (score 2):

Is it important to you that your headers are not downcase?

If it is, it shouldn't according to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), all field names are case-insensitive.