# HTTP headers became lowercased 2

Tags: java, http, post, header

I need to send UPPERcased headers via http post. The first part of story was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174741/http-headers-became-lowercased) . Now its sockets time. :)

```
Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8080);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
//      PrintStream pw = System.out;
pw.println("POST /test-servlet/TestServlet HTTP/1.0");
String params = "key1=value1&key2=value2";
pw.println("accept = text/xml");
pw.println("accept-language: ru");
pw.println("SOAPAction: requestCreditBureau");
pw.println("eif: 3");
pw.println("host: localhost");
pw.println("content-length: " + params.getBytes().length);
pw.println();
pw.println(params);
pw.println();
pw.flush();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String t;
while((t = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(t);
br.close();
```

There are two problems here.

1. It doesn't work. :) The server's servlet recive:

> workflow = TSM \
>   soapaction = requestCreditBureau 
>   eif = 3

2. There is no params in HttpServletRequest on server, only headers.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. The problem is in SOAPAction header.

Comment: You sent `"POST /test-servlet/TestServlet HTTP/1.0"` twice! You should only send it once.

Comment: @Dev: You are sending the first line two times, are you sure thats just a typo here? Also, you can update the question, in case of any changes you wish to communicate

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to reinvent the wheel with your own HTTP implementation instead of using the classes from the standard API in the java.net package?

Comment: Header names are case-insensitive by specification. Why should the case bother you?

Comment: Why are you using Socket instead of HttpUrlConnection.  HttpUrlConnection has methods to handle all the various aspects of sending an HTTP request.  It seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @CodeChimp More likely OP is trying to complete a Java class assignment and they may be mandated to use the raw APIs. To, you know, learn something :)

Comment: Sorry, for a copypast error. The first line runs only once.

Comment: There is no difference between Socket- and HttpUrlConnection way - the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `println()` method will use the systems line separator to send newlines.
HTTP defines the strict usage of `\r\n` as the line separator.
So you should hardcode the line breaks:

```
pw.print("SOAPAction: requestCreditBureau\r\n");
pw.print("eif: 3\r\n");
pw.print("host: localhost\r\n");
pw.print("content-length: " + params.getBytes().length + "\r\n");
pw.print("\r\n");
```

Consider using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` instead of implementing the HTTP protocol yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The problem was that i used tomcat7. There is no such problem using jetty.