# Meteor.http.post sets lowercase 'host' header. How do I override this?

Tags: meteor

I need to talk to a finicky web server that crashes when I execute this code:

```
payload = JSON.stringify({
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  method: 'sendMessage',
  id: 1,
  params: {
    accountID: 0,
    messageText: message,
    countDownTime: 0,
    interval: 0
  }
});
result = Meteor.http.post(api_endpoint, { content: payload });
```

After some debugging I've narrowed it down to the host header. A tcpdump of my request shows that meteor is sending it in lowercase:

```
    0x0000:  4500 00dd f959 4000 4006 162b 0a01 0b58  E....Y@.@..+...X
    0x0010:  0a01 0b3d d6a5 1388 ae92 8657 3d7b 996e  ...=.......W={.n
    0x0020:  8018 01c9 2b66 0000 0101 080a 183e 7f02  ....+f.......>..
    0x0030:  34da 9ad8 504f 5354 202f 2048 5454 502f  4...POST./.HTTP/
    0x0040:  312e 310d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74 2d54 7970  1.1..Content-Typ
    0x0050:  653a 2061 7070 6c69 6361 7469 6f6e 2f78  e:.application/x
    0x0060:  2d77 7777 2d66 6f72 6d2d 7572 6c65 6e63  -www-form-urlenc
    0x0070:  6f64 6564 0d0a 5573 6572 2d41 6765 6e74  oded..User-Agent
    0x0080:  3a20 4d65 7465 6f72 0d0a 4163 6365 7074  :.Meteor..Accept
    0x0090:  3a20 2a2f 2a0d 0a68 6f73 743a 2031 302e  :.*/*..host:.10.
    0x00a0:  312e 3131 2e36 313a 3530 3030 0d0a 636f  1.11.61:5000..co
    0x00b0:  6e74 656e 742d 6c65 6e67 7468 3a20 3135  ntent-length:.15
    0x00c0:  310d 0a43 6f6e 6e65 6374 696f 6e3a 206b  1..Connection:.k
    0x00d0:  6565 702d 616c 6976 650d 0a0d 0a         eep-alive....

    0x0000:  4500 00cb f95a 4000 4006 163c 0a01 0b58  E....Z@.@..<...X
    0x0010:  0a01 0b3d d6a5 1388 ae92 8700 3d7b 996e  ...=........={.n
    0x0020:  8018 01c9 2b54 0000 0101 080a 183e 7f02  ....+T.......>..
    0x0030:  34da 9ad9 7b22 6a73 6f6e 7270 6322 3a22  4...{"jsonrpc":"
    0x0040:  322e 3022 2c22 6d65 7468 6f64 223a 2273  2.0","method":"s
    0x0050:  656e 644d 6573 7361 6765 222c 2269 6422  endMessage","id"
    0x0060:  3a31 2c22 7061 7261 6d73 223a 7b22 6163  :1,"params":{"ac
    0x0070:  636f 756e 7449 4422 3a30 2c22 6d65 7373  countID":0,"mess
    0x0080:  6167 6554 6578 7422 3a22 4974 2077 6173  ageText":"It.was
    0x0090:  2061 2064 6172 6b20 616e 6420 7374 6f72  .a.dark.and.stor
    0x00a0:  6d79 206e 6967 6874 2e22 2c22 636f 756e  my.night.","coun
    0x00b0:  7444 6f77 6e54 696d 6522 3a30 2c22 696e  tDownTime":0,"in
    0x00c0:  7465 7276 616c 223a 307d 7d              terval":0}}
```

And this server apparently checks only for 'Host' (case sensitive) then throws an assertion error if it can't find it. Using curl, I've confirmed that the exact same request succeeds with the capitalized header name. Sadly, fixing this bad behavior in the (proprietary) server is not an option, so I have to make meteor send the values it expects.

I already tried setting the header like this:

```
result = Meteor.http.post(
  api_endpoint,
  { headers: { 'Host': instance.host }, content: payload }
);
```

but the host header still gets sent in lowercase.

How do I override the host header properly?

Using meteor 0.6.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174838/219238), HTTP RFC 2616 states that header field names are case-insensitive, so the calling behavior is correct by spec.

If you are making the call from the client then try converting to a Meteor method and executing it on the server.  Meteor client-side uses the 
browser's [XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/http/httpcall_client.js#L80) object so it will be browser-dependent.  (You would see the same behavior using jQuery since it also uses the same browser objects.)

Meteor server-side uses Node's request function so first test that to see if it preserves case.

If not, since fixing the remote server is not possible, you will have to proxy the call through a server you control that can send the headers in the format required.  That can either mean finding one that let's you control header case (maybe even dropping down to curl) or doing low-level string manip on the raw request.

So I think a plan of action is:

1. Test server-side Meteor.call
2. Find/write a proxy server
3. Replace the problem client-side calls with calls to your new proxy
4. Fix request headers en-route
5. Forward on to original end-point
6. Deal with responses

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you update your code as the API changes, meteor is still in a preview release so stuff keeps changing. `Meteor.http` is now just `HTTP`.

So it looks like meteor converts headers to lowercase (see [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/http/httpcall_client.js#L143)). You need to alter some meteor packages to get it to work how you want.

Alter what you're looking for you need to make yourself a custom HTTP package.

1) Get the files over from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/http/

2) Create a folder, if you don't aleady have one, called `packages` in your project's root directory and in it another directory `HTTP`

3) Add all the files you got from 1 in this `HTTP` directory.

4) run `meteor add HTTP` to override the default `HTTP` package with your one.

5) Alter the file `httpcall_client.js` at Line 143 (as at version Meteor 0.6.5.1) to alter the part that converts headers to lowercase so that they're used as is.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip about API changes! Changing that line 143 didn't work for me though. Looking back, it's in the callback on complete function so it doesn't influence the request.

Will keep digging, and I'll keep the steps about packages in mind when I need to tweak meteor in the future.